# Can not Update Sqlite Database with Cursor and Calling onClickListener

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

This is Method Cursor on DatabaseHelper;

```
public Cursor updateNewQuiz(int n, String s) {
    return getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("UPDATE tb_characters SET LOCKED = '" + s + "' WHERE ID = '" + n + "'", null);
}

 public Cursor updateThisQuiz(int n) {
    return getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("UPDATE tb_characters SET ANSWERED = '1' WHERE ID = '" + n + "'", null);
}
```

And, I was Calling OnClickLIstener in Acticity like this

```
int nn = Integer.parseInt(resultes0);
int s = Integer.parseInt(resultes0);
Cursor cursor = myDb.updateNewQuiz(nn+1,"1");
Cursor cursor1 = myDb.updateThisQuiz(s);
```

But, my database it still Does not UPDATE...

Please Help Me ....

Comment: Is the ID in the database a string or a number?

Comment: the ID in database is INTEGER..., and ther resultes0 is getExtras.String from Database ID..

Comment: Why are you adding quotes around the values?

Comment: Cause  I want to set the value always "1" SET LOCKED = '" + s + "' when update the database... i'm very confusing about this... cause the LogCat is not show an error...

Comment: `rawQuery()` is used for **SQL queries** (***`SELECT`***). For **SQL commands** (everything else), use `execSQL()`, instead. It doesn't return anything. Other than this, as @CL said, **numeric** values aren't matched if you pass **strings** to them.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) says:

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes (').

So `... WHERE ID = '" + n + "' ...` searches for a row that has a string as the ID. There is no such row, so nothing gets updated.

In SQL, you must write numbers without quotes:

```
... WHERE ID = " + n + " ...
```

Furthermore, you must use [execSQL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) to execute statements that are not SELECT queries.

It might be a better idea to use [update()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) instead:

```java
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("LOCKED", 1);
db.update("tb_characters", cv, "ID = " + n, null);
```

Comment: The database is not update..., Any problem with my Public Cursor ? or What... i have no idea...